# How to get additional lines of context in a CloudWatch Insights query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I typically run a query like

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /ERROR/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Is there any way to get additional lines of context around the messages containing "ERROR"? Similar to the A, B, and C flags with grep?

#### Example

For example, if I have a given log with the following lines

```
DEBUG Line 1
DEBUG Line 2
ERROR message
DEBUG Line 3
DEBUG Line 4
```

Currently I get the following result

```
ERROR message
```

But I would like to get more context lines like

```
DEBUG Line 2
ERROR message
DEBUG Line 3
```

with the option to get more lines of context if I want.

Comment: Can you show an example of input data, and current and expected outcome of the query?

Comment: Would you consider pulling the surrounding lines from the log file using the error message as a solution? (I know it is not ideal)

Comment: @Uuuuuumm I'm not sure I follow your suggestion, can you please elaborate? Are you suggesting something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393140/4059062)?

Comment: Pretty much, except it seems like @Kevin knows what he is talking about. lol

Comment: Im looking for a similar solution. I used to do a grep on a log file with -A and -B parameters, wondering if something is present in log insights as well.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can actually query the `@logStream` as well, which in the results will be a link to the exact spot in the respective log stream of the match:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| filter @message like /ERROR/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

That will give you a column similar to the right-most one in this screenshot:

[image]

Clicking the link to the right will take you to and highlight the matching log line. I like to open this in a new tab and look around the highlighted line for context.

Comment: This works well, thank you. I still wish I could get the extra context in the query itself so I could look at multiple errors and their context all at once but this will do for now.

Comment: +1, but it's probably worth mentioning that -- if I'm not mistaken -- the '@logStream' field will only be linkified if you're searching in only one log-group.

Comment: If searching across multiple logs, the `@logStream` will be linkified again if you also include `@log` in the field list

Comment: Thanks, @RevBingo. I've been limiting myself to one log at a time for this very reason and it drives me bonkers. I'll have to try that out next time.

Comment: is `like` case sensitive ?

Comment: @Akhil Yes, but if you need to match substrings with case-insensitive patterns you can use a regular expression with the `(?i)` parameter, e.g.: ```
fields f1, f2, f3 
| filter f1 like /(?i)Exception/
```

Answer (score 21):

I found that the most useful solution is to do your query and search for errors and get the request id from the "requestId" field and open up a second browser tab. In the second tab perform a search on that request id.

Example:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @requestId like /fcd09029-0e22-4f57-826e-a64ccb385330/ 
| sort @timestamp asc
| limit 500
```

With the above query you get all the log messages in the correct order for the request where the error occurred. This is an example that works out of the box with lambda. But if you push logs to CloudWatch in a different way and there is no requestId i would suggest creating a requestId per request or another identifier that is more useful for you use case and push that with your log event.

Comment: Yeah I use this trick currently. I'm looking for an improvement on this method. I should have mentioned this workaround in my question. I think this may be useful for others though, so thanks for adding it.

Comment: I've come across client applications that don't have a requestId. In such cases, i generally use the timestamp window (which is timeconsuming but accurate)

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the `@timestamp` from one of the returned lines. Then you can comment out the `@message` filter and add a range filter based off of that timestamp. Like the following.

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| filter
  #  @message like /ERROR/
  # and 
  @timestamp < 1686761438259 and @timestamp > 1686761418259
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

You can expand and retract the range as you need.

Although more time consuming and not as simple as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427447/9530790) it allows you to stay within the Logs Insights query window so you can benefit from the speed and not have to click

[image: load older events]

and wait for more records to load.

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393140/9530790) just it'll work even if you don't have `@requestId` (which was our case). I imagine this may have been what @SanjoS30 had in mind.